# C# Multi-Producer/Multi-Tiered Multi-Consumer Losing Data

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer, missing-data

I have a built complex application using a multi-tiered producer-consumer pattern, with multiple consumers performing specialized tasks before enqueing data to the next group of consumers. The ultimate job of the application is to break down a raw data file into test records for individual units that that will have been normalized.

The base of the P-C pattern uses Dustin Hyun's pattern from http://dustin-hyun.blogspot.com/2013_07_01_archive.html. I have made numerous modifications because of the multiple tiered approach and others. The code is too complex to post here- perhaps I could post snippets upon request to help clarify and answer questions.

I have employed two tools to speed up how a file gets processed. First is multiple instances of any of the tiers of consumer- there could be eight "index" consumers running whose jobs are to convert the test data from unit IDs and Test Names to Unit Indices and Test Name Indices to normalize the results to load into the DB. Second is  the Bundling of units into merged DataTables at two point in the operation.

I have identified that data is lost intermittently, but in a fairly predictable pattern. It appears to be the last, incomplete bundle where the data was expected to have been. After the standard loop pattern, I have a check for a boolean that I use to flag if there is an incoMplete bundle, and it works:

```
if (dataToSend)  // Check if incomplete bundle to process & send prior to ending comsumer operation.
        {
            UpdateLimitsIndices(bundleNlu);
            Enqueue(StdfQType.Func, new BundledNamedTables((N_ParamRes)bundlePR.Copy(), (N_FuncRes)bundleFR.Copy(), numUnitsInCurrBundle));
        }
```

I also have put locks onto everyplace I can see where the any of the p_c entities read or write anything from any of the shared queue members. With just the locks, there appeared to be no real impact.  On a whim, I started to play with the sleep time before the loop re-spins So far, Test conditions that caused data loss with a 1ms sleep did not cause data loss during a 100 ms sleep or even a 10 ms sleep during limited testing. Could it be that the longer sleep is allowing the last piece/bundle of data to be properly processed?

I recognize that this question is vague and has few specifics because the application is too complex to post. I do hope I gave enough information for a dialog to start, however. I look for eard to heading your thoughts.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that because you are not using thread-safe collections (and neither does the author that you are basing your code on) that this may be the basis for losing data due to a concurrent write operation that fails (silently).

Luckily, along with the Task Parallel Library (TPL) .NET 4.0 gives us a whole bunch of concurrent collections which ARE thread-safe for multi-threaded environments.

Have a look at the collections in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as they are all thread-safe and their locking mechanisms are a lot faster than traditional `lock`-based objects.

Comment: There are several instances of datatables that only one thread can have write access to, so I have been using a lock. Is there a structure under the ConcurrentQueue that is a better choice, or should I keep the "lock" that I had been using with the traditional Queue?

Comment: The `ConcurrentQueue` class has locking mechanisms to ensure that the updates to the queue itself are successful if performed in a multi-threaded fashion. I would suggest that keeping the lock mechanism you have in place for the single-thread access datatables would be a good idea, however only lock while you are making the update required to the table and any other updates should be outside (i.e. to queues etc) should be outside the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is very difficult to get right, and it appears that you have not gotten it right. Also, why are you (and the author of that blog post) using sleep intervals rather than `Monitor.Pulse()`?

Rather than trying to implement this yourself, why not use a library that will give you a slightly higher level of abstraction above the underlying thread coordination mechanism?

- [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Anthony and ToadFlakz. I am not a programmer by training, and have relied on sources like Dustin's blog and this site for tips and insights. I saw some suggestions yesterday before posting of using ConcurrentQueue, but I was hesitant to make such as extreme change without knowing must about this structure. Can it simply replace the Queue in my current classes? I am too far along to totally rewrite everything- unless absolutely required!

Comment: Sorry to double comment on my own post....  I have modified the class that implements the several Queues to instead use ConcurrentQueues. I also blindly commented out all of the locks I had in place. After I noticed that the application was "hanging up" when the various consumers would check if their work was "completed" before shutting down. They would not shut down even though their work was in fact complete because the counter I am using was relying on the dequeue lock. I have reinstated a lock, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've arrived at a solution, but a cargo cult, copy and paste approach to threading is going to lead to nothing but pain in the long term.

Comment: I said that the "base" used that P-C pattern. I modified it extensively to fit my needs, adding many items and dropping others by following examples on this and other internet boards. Thanks for all the help, although I may not be 100% out of the woods, as testing has rediscovered another problem I don't quite understand yet.